# How to add a tab bar to flipside view only

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, tabbar

I already have the basic code for a utility application, but when the application flips to the second view I want to add a `tabbarItem` to the bottom of the flipped view only, if the view is flipped back to the original view the tab bar shouldn't show up. How can I add this feature, I'm using simulator 4.1 by the way, thanks!

Here's the code that shows the flipped side when the button is clicked, I want it to flip to a tab bar controller instead.

```
- (IBAction)showInfo:(id)sender {    

    FlipsideViewController *controller = [[FlipsideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FlipsideView" bundle:nil];
    controller.delegate = self;

    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

    [controller release];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the `UITabbar` by using the following code

`[yourTabBar setHidden :YES];`

and show it using the following code

`[yourTabBar setHidden:NO];`

Comment: Ok I think I have that, but how do I SHOW/SETUP the tabbar in the first place?

Comment: Would be useful if you used just one answer. If you need to add anything new then just to your existing answer. Thanks.

Comment: I had code in it so couldnt put it in comments. and the earlier answers had little code..so had to put them in comments.

Answer (score 1):

By Show/Setup do you mean adding the tabbar controller on the view??Well i am assuming that..You can Add the tabbar controller as a rootviewcontroller of your window i.e. your AppDelegate.Here is the sample Code:

```
UIViewController *viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navCon1=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController1];

UIViewController *viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navCon2=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController2];

UIViewController *viewController3=[[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navCon3=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController3];

self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navCon1, navCon2,navCon3, nil];

self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
```

Comment: Ok and this won't add a tabbar to the first view, right, only the second? I'll try it out.

Comment: This will add the tabbar to your window not any view.
But you can hide the tabbar ina ny view controller using the code i gave you before.

Comment: Sorry this didn't work. I need the self.window.rootViewController to = self.mainViewController, which is the first view. Once you click the button in first view then it should take you to the next view (flipped view)with the tabbar controller.

Answer (score 0):

You're switching between two `UIViewControllers`, right? Let the second view controller, the one that appears after flipping, be a `UITabBarViewController`.